# Modify describe function to remove and add columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with 3 columns. Each column contains `yes`,`no`, or `nan`.
I am trying to find the frequency of each column based on column `a`. I was able to do this with `describe()`.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['yes','yes','no','yes','no','yes'],
                        'b':['no','yes','no','yes','no','no'],
                        'c':['yes','yes','yes','no','no', np.nan]})

df2.groupby('a').describe().transpose()

a    no                   yes                 
  count unique top freq count unique  top freq
b     2      1  no    2     4      2   no    2
c     2      2  no    1     3      2  yes    2
```

I am having trouble selecting the `describe` columns I want. Below is an example of how I would like it to look. The `freq/total_count` column is the `freq` over total `freq` of the row. For example, `b` & `no` is `2/6`.

```
a    no                                      yes                
  count top freq freq/total_count   count top freq freq/total_count
b     2  no    2     33%             4    no    2     33% 
c     2  no    1     20%             3   yes    2     40%
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Sorry but why aren't the expected values 50% 50%, 0.333% 0.666%? as the first row total is `2+2=4` and last row is `1+2=3`

Comment: I wanted to do it over `2+4=6` and `2+3=5` because I wanted to do it over the total number of observations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. The `df2.groupby('a').describe().transpose()` command gives a DataFrame with a MultiIndex. To select/manipulate individual pieces of the DataFrame, you have to first select the 'yes' or 'no' index, then the column index.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['yes','yes','no','yes','no','yes'],
                    'b':['no','yes','no','yes','no','no'],
                    'c':['yes','yes','yes','no','no', np.nan]})

data = df2.groupby('a').describe().transpose()

data['no','freq/total_count']=np.nan
data['yes','freq/total_count']=np.nan

for ind in data.index:
    data['no','freq/total_count'][ind] = data['no']['freq'][ind]/(data['no']['count'][ind]+data['yes']['count'][ind])*100
    data['yes','freq/total_count'][ind] = data['yes']['freq'][ind]/(data['no']['count'][ind]+data['yes']['count'][ind])*100


data['no','freq/total_count'] = data['no','freq/total_count'].map('{0:.0f}%'.format)
data['yes','freq/total_count'] = data['yes','freq/total_count'].map('{0:.0f}%'.format)
```

The output is

```
a   no                          yes                           no                 yes
    count  unique  top   freq   count   unique   top   freq   freq/total_count   freq/total_count
b   2      1       no    2      4       2        no    2      33%                33%
c   2      2       no    1      3       2        yes   2      20%                40%
```

To pretty print this, we want to remove the 'unique' column header. Then put the 'no' section together and the 'yes' section together.

```
del data['no','unique']
del data['yes','unique']
pd.concat([data['no'],data['yes']],axis=1,keys=['no','yes'])
```

Giving the final output:

```
a   no                                     yes
    count  top   freq   freq/total_count   count   top   freq   freq/total_count
b   2      no    2      33%                4       no    2      33%
c   2      no    1      20%                3       yes   2      40%
```

Comment: thanks, but how do you get rid of `unique` for all columns?

Comment: The command `del data['no', 'unique']` will delete the `unique` in the 'no' section. Do the same with 'yes' as well